# Simple way to share angular app with others?

Tags: angular

I am building an Angular app and I would like to share it with some people so they can see the progress and try it out. Is there a simple way to do this?

I thought that after I run `ng build` and send the content of the dist folder to them they could simply drag the `index.html` file into their browser and it would work. However, the routing of the app is not working when I do this. So I guess I would either like to know how to fix the routing or know if there is an easy alternative. They are not technical people, so I don't want to make them install things and run it through the command line. Just for the record, the application is working fine when using `ng serve`. Thanks.

Comment: you can use github

Comment: Can they run it from github? @Simonare

Comment: ah if your intention is endusers. you can try heroku

Answer (score 2):

If your main test user scope is Developers, then you can upload your solution to Git Repository and let them clone your project, compile, debug, run, etc. GitHub is version control platform.

If your intention is to host your application for end users, then you can use any hosting services. Even IF you have static IP, you can host your site by yourself in your own computer. But the free alternative would be heroku. Also you can consider to use Firebase as well.

Comment: Yeah, my intention was to share it with users, not developers. I am already using firebase for my database, but I was looking for a free solution to share it with them. Haven't heard of Heroku, but I will definitely check it out. Thank you very much.